# Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Tags: mysql

My table structrure:

```
CREATE TABLE `goal_review` (
    `id` BIGINT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_review_info` BIGINT(25) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_OBJECTIVE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_CONDITION` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_MEASURE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_TIMING` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_TYPE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_WEIGHTAGE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_OBJECTIVE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_CONDITION` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_MEASURE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_TIMING` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_TYPE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_WEIGHTAGE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_OBJECTIVE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_CONDITION` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_MEASURE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_TIMING` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_TYPE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_WEIGHTAGE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_OBJECTIVE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_CONDITION` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_MEASURE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_TIMING` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_TYPE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_WEIGHTAGE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_COMMENTS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_OBJECTIVE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_CONDITION` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_MEASURE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_TIMING` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_TYPE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_WEIGHTAGE` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_goal_review_user_review_info` (`user_review_info`),
    INDEX `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRBUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRBUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRBUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRBUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRLONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRLONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` (`LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRLONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    INDEX `FK_GRLONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` (`LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRLONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRLONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRLONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`LONG_TERM_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRLONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`LONG_TERM_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_goal_review_user_review_info` FOREIGN KEY (`user_review_info`) REFERENCES `user_review_info` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRBUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRBUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`BUSINESS_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRBUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRBUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`BUSINESS_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPLIANCE_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRCOMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPLIANCE_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRPROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJECT_DELIVERY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_ANNUAL_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_MANAGER_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GRSKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING` FOREIGN KEY (`SKILL_COMPETENCY_MID_REVIEW_SELF_RATING`) REFERENCES `appraisal_rating` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I can insert minimum datas but I am unable to insert even 500 characters for the `LONGTEXT` fields.

I tried `BLOB`s, and `TEXT` instead of `LONG TEXT`.

Comment: This looks like one hell of a table. Are you sure it shouldn't be split?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: A cursory look at this you can see "Skill", "Project" and "Business" relationships and many many more.

Comment: LONGTEXT allows you to store 4 gigabytes of text. Do you really need that much data in each field of your table? Maybe using TEXT (64kilobytes) type instead is a better idea?

Comment: ok friends i can't to normalize it is a dynamic table i find out problem  and post here

Answer (score 0):

Blob is used to store data in binary format while TEXT stores large String.

BLOB values are treated as binary strings. They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.

TEXT values are treated as nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set, and values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character set.

Text format messages should almost always be stored as TEXT.

Comment: The original poster is using LONGTEXT, which is a kind of TEXT. See the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).

Comment: Looks like appraisal form process application. You have to store managers comments in table. So I think TEXT is enough. Go with TEST.

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

Comment: sir i changed to TEXT and also  ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED thanks advance

Comment: no sir just i install new mysql-5.6.10.1 change longtext to text then retry i got this error

Comment: again also i got same error  org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs i unable to solve this please help me sir .Also i want to know y come this because i used text . my thought is texxt and blobs are not count for row size

Comment: very very urgent last three day  i has stuck with this issue i can update minimum character ex each row 10 char but i cant add more character ex each column 1000 char

Comment: I guess there are too many columns having TEXT data type. So making it TEXT from BLOB is not helping. Still it's going out of memory. Think of normalizing the table.

Answer (score 0):

**hi friends** ,
mistake is myself. mysql have to write file for each column longtext or text  this file information only stored in table . this file need unique name this name generated by our inpunt . i try to enter same input for all columns .
so mysql engine take that index too long from my input(for unique file name ) that's why it take more row size above 65,535 byte. i try to enter different input it was taken by mysql engine without error . if my throught is wrong please give your answers
once again thx to Jeevan Patil for quick reply

Answer (score 0):

It could be a more complex problem but for the purposes of development just add to `my.cnf/my.ini`:

```
[mysqld]
#...
innodb_strict_mode = 0
```